# Use namespace Threading or not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

There are two ways you can write this piece of code which contains a Sleep Method from the namespace `Threading`.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timespan interval = new Timespan(0,0,2);
        //Creating a Timespan which is 2 seconds.
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) ;
        {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(interval);
        //Making my thread go to sleep for two seconds.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }

    }
  }
}
```

However, you can also do it this way

```
using System;
using System.Threading; 
//Added the namespace in which the method Sleep comes from.

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
        Thread.Sleep(interval); 
        //This line does the same as the one above.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }

     }
   }
 }
```

I know that you should probably avoid using the namespace because it could create conflicts if you are using two libraries with the same method in it.

Is there any other reasons to use/not to use the namespace?
Performance, etc.?

Comment: You could also remove `using System;`, and instead type `System.TimeSpan`, `System.Console.WriteLine`, `System.DateTime`, over and over again. But why would you do that? `using` statements are there to save you from this hassle.

Comment: I would just not use Thread.Sleep at all and find a different way :)

Comment: If you are using another library with a function/method namned Timespan(not so likely, but still), it will create conflicts.

Comment: Personally, I think the only reason you'd declare the full namespace is in order to avoid conflicts (which isn't very likely in this scenario). Otherwise, it's just additional noise in the code

Comment: Rather than `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)`, use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

> To allow the use of types in a namespace so that you do not have to
>   qualify the use of a type in that namespace

For your statement in question:

> I know that you should probably avoid using the namespace because it
>   could create conflicts if you are using two libraries with the same
>   method in it

That is not correct. Not using namespaces in code would produce more noise in the code. Imagine writing `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectione` everywhere instead of `SqlConnection`

If their is a conflict in namespaces then you can always explicitly specify your namespace with the code or use an alias with using directive.

Comment: or `System.Security.Cryptography.Aes` :)